# Jackson ObjectMapper with '/' Character as JSON key

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

**JSON Setup (my-file.json):**

```
 { ":x.y\/a" : "some value" }
```

**ObjectMapper:**

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.configure( JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_BACKSLASH_ESCAPING_ANY_CHARACTER, true );
Map value = om.readValue( getClass().getResource( "/my-file.json" ).getFile() , HashMap.class );
```

I have also tried using JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_COMMENTS (which doesn't really make sense but I thought what the heck).  However, regardless of how I try to configure this, I can seem to read the JSON into the Map.

**Exception**

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('/' (code 47)): maybe a (non-standard) comment? (not recognized as one since Feature 'ALLOW_COMMENTS' not enabled for parser)
at [Source: java.io.StringReader@31c74456; line: 1, column: 2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1524)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:557)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:475)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._skipComment(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1725)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._skipWSOrEnd(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1708)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:562)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2926)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2873)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2034)
```

Any thoughts on how I could configure this would be appreciated.  As a temporary workaround I've used the Gson library which parses this same file just fine.

```
new Gson().fromJson( new FileReader( getClass().getResource( /my-file.json ).getFile() ), HashMap.class );
```

While this does work, I prefer Jackson as we use it everywhere else in our stack (nothing against Gson, just don't want to add it as a dependency right now).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is in `getClass().getResource( "/my-file.json" ).getFile()`. `getFile()` returns file path and not file content. `ObjectMapper` `readValue(String content, ..)` function takes content as its first argument. You can use

```
Map value = om.readValue(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/my-file.json"), HashMap.class);
```

`om.readValue(new FileReader(path), HashMap.class);` like your Gson example would also work

Comment: "not file content", and more importantly, not a `File` object

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I should have looked closer at that. Probably not the best name for a method but I'll own this mistake. 